# Add method to any instance of a class at runtime

Tags: java, reflection

I have a method that looks like this

```
public Collection<V> values()
```

At runtime i would like to add a field and getter method to V.

let me give you an example

```
Collection<Person> persons = map.values();
```

or

```
Collection<OtherObject> otherObjectCollection = map.values();
```

i would like to make sure that any instance will always have a field/method,

```
persons.getXXX();
otherObjectCollection.getXXX();
```

so in my

```
map.values()
```

i would like to be able to add a field and methods to my V instance at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, basically. You can't add fields and methods to types at execution time in Java. You may want to create your own type to *wrap* the original type and maintain a `Map<String, Objet>` for additional values:

```
public final class Annotated<T> {
    private final Map<String, Object> annotations = new HashMap<>();
    private final T wrapped;

    public Annotated(T wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public T getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    public void setAnnotation(String name, Object value) {
        annotations.put(name, value);
    }

    public Object getAnnotation(String name) {
        return annotations.get(name);
    }
}
```

That won't help you add *methods* of course, but it's not clear why you'd want to... my guess is that you've come from a background in a dynamically typed language. Don't try to apply the same idioms to Java - they won't work well. Instead, take a look at the bigger picture of what you're trying to accomplish, and figure out the most appropriate Java-like approach to it.

Comment: Well, let me try to explain a little more what i am doing.
I have a class that can take some kind of objects, the objects can be anything pretty much. Then i can apply a search filter and i will get back a list of hits.
That list contains the original object type. But i want to know how good the search was. Was it 100% match or a 10% match.
But since i do not know the instance of my object i cannot calculate the percentage. But if i could add that method in runtime i would be able to call getHitRate() on any instance...

Comment: @BeauJohnnyBekkestad: Do all your classes have a `getHitRate` method? If so, put that in an interface. It does sound like you should be returning a `Collection<SearchResult<Foo>>` instead of a `Collection<Foo>` though.

Comment: That would only work if i supply the class... If you supply the class for me then the situation is different.
I could expose an API for you to implement, but that is not what i was looking to do in this example...
Ofcourse, if i cannot do what i was thinking then i would have to take a different approach.

Comment: @BeauJohnnyBekkestad: Well it's very unclear exactly what you *are* trying to do, but you definitely *can't* add fields or methods to existing objects in Java, so you'll need a different approach... and I'd *strongly* urge you to consider using composition here. A search result with metadata is *not* the same as just the result itself.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving that functionality out to a separate Analyzer class.